# How to get payload mime type in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mime-types, mule-studio, payload, dataweave

I am trying to find out what is the payload type by printing it out using logger. I am aware that in Mule 3 you could use this `#[payload.getClass().getSimpleName()]` or `#[message.dataType.type]`.

How to achieve this in Mule 4? I did my google search but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
#[payload.^class]
```

Try logging:

```
#[payload.^]
```

Should print:

{class=java.util.ArrayList, encoding=UTF-8, mimeType=application/java, raw=[{}]}

But if your payload is not application/java mime/type but json or something instead it won't have class attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work - prints "null"

Comment: `#[payload.^]` works just like I want. Perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Get payload media type: #[payload.^mediaType]

Reference: https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-cookbook-extract-data